# Jacoco 0.8.7 coverage data is invalid. Error

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using jacoco 0.8.7 and for some classes I am getting this error when I try to export jacoco xml to Sonarqube.

```
Cannot import coverage information for file 'src/main/java/com/some/package/MyClass.kt', coverage data is invalid. Error: {}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 88 is out of range in the file src/main/java/com/some/package/MyClass.kt (lines: 87)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:61)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.coverage.internal.DefaultCoverage.validateLine(DefaultCoverage.java:81)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.coverage.internal.DefaultCoverage.lineHits(DefaultCoverage.java:69)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.ReportImporter.importCoverage(ReportImporter.java:45)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoSensor.importReport(JacocoSensor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoSensor.importReports(JacocoSensor.java:62)
        at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JacocoSensor.execute(JacocoSensor.java:47)
```